# Potential malware uploaded to a storage account vs Potential malware uploaded to a storage blob container

Tags: azure, azure-defender, azure-security-center, azure-workflow-automation

According to this [guide](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-security-center/how-to-respond-to-potential-malware-uploaded-to-azure-storage/ba-p/1452005), the name for the alert from Azure Defender that is created when a malicious file is uploaded to a blob container is "Potential malware uploaded to a storage account".

However, when I look in Azure Security Center, it says "Potential malware uploaded to a storage blob container":

[image]

Which one is the correct one to use in the workflow automation "alert name contains" field?

[image]

I noticed in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security-center/alerts-reference they don't have "Potential malware uploaded to a storage blob container" listed

Is it possible that they haven't updated the document?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the workflow to trigger on "Potential malware uploaded to a storage blob container" and it's working.

I've informed the author of that article.

I'm assuming they have not updated https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security-center/alerts-reference.